# MySQL Data from two tables: Adding column headings to output

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I use following to get data from two tables:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.event_date, a.name, p.location_id 
FROM ixrsk_eb_events p 
INNER JOIN ixrsk_eb_locations a on p.location_id = a.id
```

This works fine.

Now in addition, I want to have column headings. 
On top of the results: "ID" (col `p.id`), "Title" (col `p.title`), "Date" (col `p.event_date`) and "Location" (col `a.name`).

And column `p.location_id` should not be displayed at all (no heading, no data).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use aliases to change the names of the columns you show:

```
SELECT 
  p.id AS ID, 
  p.title AS Title, 
  p.event_date AS Date, 
  a.name AS Location
FROM ixrsk_eb_events p 
INNER JOIN ixrsk_eb_locations a on p.location_id = a.id
```

and just leave out the columns you do not want to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for aliasing the column/expressions. Refer this tutorial for further explanation: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

```
SELECT p.id AS ID, 
       p.title AS Title, 
       p.event_date AS Date, 
       a.name AS Location
       -- removed p.location_id 
FROM ixrsk_eb_events p 
INNER JOIN ixrsk_eb_locations a on p.location_id = a.id
```

To skip a particular column, you simply need to remove that from the `SELECT` clause.